# Expression template operator overloading problem with std::vector

Tags: c++, templates, stl, operator-overloading, expression-templates

I'm currently working on a numerical library that uses expression templates. Unfortunately I encountered a problem with my operator overloads. Consider the following stripped down example.

```
#include <vector>

namespace test {
    class test {};

    template<class A, class B>
    class testExpr {};

    template<class A, class B>
    testExpr<A, B>
    operator-(A a, B b)
    {
        return testExpr<A, B>();
    }
}

test::test
stuff(std::vector<test::test> &v)
{ return v.back(); }

int main()
{ }
```

Which gives the following error message when compiling with gcc 4.4.3 or clang 2.8:

```
In file included from eir_test.cc:2:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.4/vector:64:
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_vector.h:696:16: error: indirection requires pointer operand
      ('testExpr<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<test::test *, std::vector<test::test, std::allocator<test::test> > >, int>' invalid)
      { return *(end() - 1); }
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~
eir_test.cc:21:12: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::vector<test::test, std::allocator<test::test> >::back' requested here
    return v.back();
           ^
1 error generated.
```

For some reason the compilers do a lookup into the test namespace and find my general operator. I used this form together with some traits magic to reduce the number of version i had to make for the operator. It should accept 4 different datatypes (including double and int) which would lead to a lot of different combinations.

Is there any way to make this work without spelling out all combinations for every operator?

Comment: Does your precise example fail to compile? I was able to compile it just fine on g++ 4.4.1.

Comment: The error message is from clang. g++ fails there, too, but the error message is worse. I also tried gcc version 4.3.4 (Ubuntu 4.3.4-10ubuntu1) and gcc version 4.1.3 20080704 (prerelease) (Ubuntu 4.1.2-27ubuntu1). Both fail.

Comment: fails with gcc 3.4.6, **compiles** with gcc 4.4.1, fails with gcc 4.4.4, gcc 4.5.2, gcc 4.6-alpha. Error is the same (no operator* on the result of operator- between vector::iterator and an int)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `end()` returns a type that is a class template specialization which has one argument of type `test::test *`. Thus when `operator-` is applied in the expression `end() - 1`, argument dependent lookup looks *also* in the namespace of `test::test`. It finds your `operator-` and passes it the iterator and an `int`.

You could fix it by not accepting any and all types as arguments. For example, try accepting `(testExpr<A1, B1>, testExpr<A2, B2>)` instead. Show all your combinations, possibly there is a way to cut them down using another way to formulate them?

In my opinion, an implementation that acts that way should be non-conforming (I think this is really disgusting though). Because doing `iterator - 1` is specified to yield another iterator to the previous element and must not do something crazy like that, I think. One way for it is to declare operator as a non-template accepting the iterator type and the integer argument (which is of the iterator's `difference_type`) directly. This way their version should always be preferred.

Comment: While I'm still not sure if this is a bug or an inaccuracy in the standard, I decided to ship around by generating the necessary combinations with a script.

Answer (score 0):

Your code compiles OK in VC++ version 10 (from Visual Studio 2010 C++ Express), even when modified like this:

```
int main()
{ 
    vector<test::test> vec;
    test::test instance = stuff(vec);

    return 0;
}
```

This could be a  limitation of the compilers. Expression templates are somewhat of a stress test for a compiler's template support.